# How do I remove positional parameters in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, parameters, arguments

I have a script that takes parameters and I want to remove given named parameters

e.g. script.sh a b c
and I want to remove 'b' so that

```
    $1 = a
    $2 = c
```

This also must work for any given set of args such that e.g.

```
    script.sh "a 1" b "c 2"
    $1 = "a 1"
    $2 = "c 2"
```

A previous answer said

```
    for var in "$@"; do
        case $var in
            "a") echo -n $var ;;
            "b") ;;
        esac
    done
```

The generic version of the previous answer should have been (in order to remove b)

```
    for var in "$@"; do
        case $var in
            "b") ;;
            *) echo -n $var ;;
        esac
    done
```

But this fails for multiple parameters
e.g.

```
    script.sh a b c
    Output: ac
```

We wanted a b
and we wanted them in positional parameter $1=a and $2=b

So a better answer is needed.

Comment: Do you want to remove the second parameter or remove all parameters with the value `b`?

Comment: Please correct any issues flagged when you paste your code into https://shellcheck.net . Be sure to start with the appropriate "she-bang" line, usually `#!/bin/bash`. Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

In the special case (commonly occurring) that you want to remove some *initial* positional parameters, you use `shift`. By default that deletes `$1`; with a numeric argument, it will delete `n` parameters.

Now, in your specific case, we can use a combination of `shift` and `set --`.

```
local a=$1
shift 2  # delete $1 and $2
set -- "$a" "$@"   # insert $1 before original $3 ... $n
```

Using Bash arrays is another possibility. If we translate the `"$@"` arguments into a bash array.

```
local args=("$@")    # convert $1 $2 ... into ${args[0]} ${args[1]} ...
unset args[1]        # delete args[1]; note: elements DO NOT SHIFT DOWN!
set -- "${args[@]}"  # convert array back to positional params
```

When we convert the array back to positional params with the "${args[@]}" expansion syntax, the unset `args[1]` element is absent, and so the original `$2` disappears.

Of course, if we need those arguments in order to pass them to a function or script, we don't have to convert the array back to positional parameters. Just:

```
local args=("$@")    # convert $1 $2 ... into ${args[0]} ${args[1]} 
unset args[1]        # delete second arg
script "${args[@]}"  # call script with second argument deleted
```

Likewise, in my very first example, we could just call whatever we need to call rather than using `set` to further edit the positionals:

```
local a=$1         # preserve $1 in temporary variable
shift 2            # delete $1 and $2
script "$a" "$@"   # call target script with original $1 $3 $4 ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean Bash code:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

args=()
for a in "$@"; do
    [[ $a == b ]] || args+=( "$a" )
done
set -- "${args[@]}"

(( $# > 0 )) && printf '%s\n' "$@"
```

- When run with arguments `'a 1' b 'c 2'` it produces output

  ```
  a 1
  c 2
  ```
- When run with arguments `-x "a'1" b 'c 2' "'\$(echo REBOOTING >&2)'"` it produces output

  ```
  -x
  a'1
  c 2
  '$(echo REBOOTING >&2)'
  ```
- The `--` argument to `set` prevents subsequent arguments (e.g. `-x`) being treated as options.

Answer (score 1):

I presented two options, a solution to your problem and in addition a more proper way of hanlding input arguments.

**To Answer your question**

Looking at this little bit of code, we exclude the argument options from the values by comparing each value to our `arg_options` array. Hence anything define in `arg_options` will not be in the final results.

The script loops over every input option, then runs another check (loop) to look for any matches in our arg options, if it's found we mark it as a value we don't want and we move on.

```
declare -a arg_options=( aaa bbb ccc ddd )

for each in "$@"; do
  found=0
  for opt in "${arg_options[@]}"; do
     if [ "$each" = "$opt" ]; then
        found=1
        break
     fi
  done
  if [ $found -ne 1 ]; then
          echo $each 
          # store to an array etc. here
  fi
done
```

**To expand on your question**

Take this example 'script.sh' with command line options:

```
Script.sh -mode active -count 10
```

Here's the code, and the nice part is that it will properly handle the inputs no matter what order they are passed to the script:

```
typeset mode='inactive'
typeset count

get_user_input_options() {
    while [[ $# > 0 ]] ;do
        key="$1"
        case ${key,,} in
            -m|--mode)
                mode="$2"
                shift
            ;;
            -c|--count)
                count="$2"
                shift
            ;;
            *)  echo "ERROR: Unknown option $key given."
                exit 1
            ;;
        esac
        shift
    done
}


get_user_input_options "$@" # handle user inputs (if any)
```

What are we doing in the script, we are defining a function to read in the options and set the global variables `get_user_input_options`. Look at how it is being called, it is taking in all of the command line inputs for handling with the `"$@"` option. *Note: if you don't want it to be a script just remove the function line and it's closing bracket.*

Then it is using a while loop to step over every option, but when it finds a match for an option it sets the value and shifts forward as that had the value of the option. It continues to step through the inputs until completed.

You will also notice that I set the global variable 'mode' to something so if the script is called without that option, it will be set to a default value.

Comment: "*I think you are just trying to call a script with command line options*" -- possibly, but that's not at all what the question as posed actually asks.

Comment: @JohnBollinger well dam look at that ... asked a class room question at the end.. I'll update my post

Answer (score 0):

As [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) is tagged, you can use `"${@:3}"` to produce all arguments starting from the third. Use that in combination with `$1` to reference all arguments but the second, and use `set` to reset the arguments accordingly:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

echo "BEFORE:"
for arg; do echo "=> [$arg]"; done

set -- "$1" "${@:3}"

echo "AFTER:"
for arg; do echo "=> [$arg]"; done
```

Example:

```bash
./script.sh "a 1" b "c 2"
```

```
BEFORE:
=> [a 1]
=> [b]
=> [c 2]
AFTER:
=> [a 1]
=> [c 2]
```

Comment: Based on the code fragments in the question, I think the OP wants to remove positional parameters by value, not by position.

Comment: Absolutely possible. However, based on OP's wording with the goal of `I want to remove 'b'` being part of or at least stated *after* the provided example `e.g. script.sh a b c`, I came to the opposite conclusion, and interpreted the code fragments as their first attempts to somehow approach the item in question.

Comment: @pmf This doesn't work because it should remove all b's etc. from  the results.. Also you do not account for location of the input ... anyway this must be a homework assignment it seems like a useless way to handle input args lol